# Who is Jenkins? Error /Users/jenkins/miniconda...

Tags: python, opencv, jenkins

This might be a noob question... 
I'm following this tutorial on [Emotion Recognition With Python, OpenCV and a Face Dataset](http://www.paulvangent.com/2016/04/01/emotion-recognition-with-python-opencv-and-a-face-dataset/#comment-525)

When I run the training code get the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Wrong input image size. Reason: Training and Test images must be of equal size! Expected an image with 122500 elements, but got 4.) in predict, file /Users/jenkins/miniconda/1/x64/conda-bld/conda_1486587097465/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/face/src/fisher_faces.cpp, line 132
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trainModel.py", line 64, in <module>
    correct = run_recognizer()
  File "trainModel.py", line 52, in run_recognizer
    pred, conf = fishface.predict(image)
cv2.error: /Users/jenkins/miniconda/1/x64/conda-bld/conda_1486587097465/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/face/src/fisher_faces.cpp:132: error: (-5) Wrong input image size. Reason: Training and Test images must be of equal size! Expected an image with 122500 elements, but got 4. in function predict
```

It is complaining about the image size not being 350×350=122500 although all the images in my dataset folder are the correct size 350x350px.

And my user name is not ‘jenkins’ as it says in /Users/jenkins/miniconda… not sure where it comes from or how to replace it with my correct path to fisher_faces.cpp

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about that path. The OpenCV library you are using was built on someone else's machine, and the error messages got paths from their machine baked in. It's just trying to tell you in which OpenCV source file the error is occurring in, namely [this one](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/face/src/fisher_faces.cpp#L132).

(In this case, [Jenkins](http://jenkins.io) is a popular build bot.)